# How do I make a computer boot from a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, operating-system, boot

I want to experiment with creating a custom operating system, but I the only text-based progammming language I know extensively is batch.

I had the idea to use Task Scheduler, but then I realised that this would not work without Windows having booted already.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your question makes no sense, a batch-file is a scripted set of one or more individual commands, run by specific Operating Systems. The only way this would work would be for you to copy/replicate the necessary files from one of those Operating Systems into your own. Please tell us more about your Custom Operating System, without telling us that you are really just using a pointless and limited version of the existing command line.

Comment: batch is a script file. You need `cmd.exe` to execute it. You need Windows to execute `cmd.exe`. Your approach is doomed.

Answer (score 0):

I have the authority to accept your question, which I did.

Although, on its surface it is questionable!

Don't let anyone discourage your enthusiasm.  You have selected a quest that will require a lot of work.  The first step after learning "batch" in this adventure is to learn "C".  Not C++, not python, just "C".  And, while learning "C" learn another scripting language like "bash".  After acquiring: batch, "C", and bash then you will have taken the first step into an infinitely complex world.